# I am living in Kyrgyzstan and plan to work in Argentina

Tags: argentina

I am Kyrgyz citizen and am planning to move to Argentina on a tourist visa first, then if I get a job get a work visa.

From reading online and talking to a different people there, I understand that you can come on a tourist visa and attend interviews with different companies. If you get any luck you might get hired and get a job.

Is it true that you can search for jobs while on a tourist visa there? Has anyone done something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your tourist visa doesn't forbid you from looking for jobs, but you cannot work without a work permit. Many people I know have gone job hunting to different countries on tourist visas.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this apply for Argentina, but if you try this in USA, you need to be careful.

If you entering the country on tourist visa, you should NOT volunteer to immigration officials that you plan to look for job. They might decide you plan to work illegally and deny you entry.

Once in the country, you are (after some time) "allowed" to change your mind  and look for a job, changing your intent from tourist to immigrant.

Again, not sure how strict is Argentina about this issue, but entering USA on a tourist visa and declaring you plan to look for  job might be a problem.